# variable a might no been have been initialized in bubble sort program

Tags: java

I created a bubble sort program in java but when I am compiling my program it is saying that in my program is not have been initialized

```
import java.util.*;
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[],tmp,c,i,n,j;

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the array");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-1-i;j++)
            {
                if (a[j]>a[j+1])
                {  tmp = a[j];
                   a[j] = a[j+1];
                   a[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I am compiling my program it is saying that variable a and n might not have been initialized

Comment: what if n equals 0? your for loop will never execute. not to mention, you are trying to add elements to an array that's essentially null.

Comment: This *still* will not compile since you do not initialize `a`. And even if you initialize this array, your program will do nothing since `n` is 0.

Comment: check again n is not zero.

Comment: Yes, and because n is zero your loops will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
int a[],tmp,c,i,n=0,m,j;
```

uses undefined names `m` and `j`.

Split it onto multiple lines and choose intention revealing names. Then assign a sensible value to every variable.

**Edit:**

Try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        int a[] = new int[n];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the values for the array");
        for (int i = 0; i < n ;i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n ;i++) {
            for(int j =0 ; j < n-1-i; j++) {
                if (a[j] > a[j+1]) {
                   int tmp = a[j];
                   a[j] = a[j+1];
                   a[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        // print a
    }
}
```